# Convert multiple values on datagrid to string on If condition

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a combobox. This combobox has numbers and text in it. I want to place a condition that if the combobox text is BOGO or Complimentary, then my variable dblQty should be 0.

I am able to get it to work for one condition BOGO, (see code below), but I can't seem to get it to work with 2 conditions, I tried `BOGO Or Complimentary` but I got a cannot convert to Boolean error.

```
Private Sub grdNewInvoice_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grdNewInvoice.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

    'Procedure runs when the combobox in the datagrid changes. 
    'The procedure calculates the amount * the quantity in the datagrid
    'It also updates the label with the total

    'Local variables
    Dim dblQty As Double
    Dim dblPrice As Double

    'Calculate the amount * quantity
    For index As Integer = 0 To grdNewInvoice.RowCount - 1

        If grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value.ToString = "BOGO" Then

            dblQty = 0
            dblPrice = Convert.ToDouble(grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(2).Value)

            grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value = dblPrice * dblQty

        Else

            dblQty = Convert.ToDouble(grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value)
            dblPrice = Convert.ToDouble(grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(2).Value)

            grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value = dblPrice * dblQty

        End If

    Next

    'Update the total label.
    PublicSubs.totalDataGrid()

End Sub
```

Comment: whats is the code you tried for `BOGO Or Complimentary`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the passing comment in the post that `I tried BOGO Or Complimentary` it sounds like you may have tried this:

```
If grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value.ToString = "BOGO" 
          Or "Complimentary" Then
```

Which is not how OR works.  The second test can be for something altogether different such as

```
If thisThing = "BOGO" Or Sale.BlackFriday = True Then ...
```

Try this:

```
Dim thing As String = grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value.ToString 

If thing = "BOGO" Or Thing = "Complimentary" Then...
```